# How to split string and add string positions of elements before the split?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, split, position

Example:

```
s="  300       january      10       20     " 
mylist = s.split()
mylist = ['300', 'january', '10', '20']
```

How can I create a list adding the string position of the elements before the splitting:

```
mylistStringPos = [['300',startpos:endpos],...] 
mylistStringPos = [['300',2:5], '['january',12:19]', '['10',25:27]', '['20',34:36]']]
```

Is there a way in Python to do this?

Comment: What type is `2:5`? Is it a string, `'2:5'`? What about the `[['300', 2, 5], ['january', 12, 19], ['10', 25, 27], ['20', 34, 36]]` output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `re` with the `\S+` pattern to match non-whitespace chunks of text and access [`m.group()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group), [`m.start()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start) and [`m.end()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.end) to collect the necessary data:

```
import re
s="  300       january      10       20     "
print([[x.group(), x.start(), x.end()] for x in re.finditer(r'\S+', s)])
# => [['300', 2, 5], ['january', 12, 19], ['10', 25, 27], ['20', 34, 36]]
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/mpIgHv)

Comment: so easy :) Thanks Wiktor

Comment: Wiktor, just a last question: if I want to split the string only when there are 2 spaces of more between the elements, how do I have to adapt the finditer regex?

Comment: Use [`r'\S+(?:\s\S+)*'`](https://regex101.com/r/Qr9sRX/1). Or if you only process *lines*, `r'\S+(?:[^\S\r\n]\S+)*'`.